# Help to understand: "have arrested" vs "have been arrested"

Tags: present-perfect

I want to know difference between these example.If 2nd example is correct then i want to know the process is still going on or not.

1) Police have arrested two men in connection with the robbery

2) Police have been arrested two men in connection with the robbery.

Comment: If you want to use "have been", then "police have been *arresting* men in connection with the robbery", in which case it could be that the process is still going on in that the police plan to arrest more people in connection with the robbery. Or "two men have been arrested in connection with the robbery". It is the men who have been *arrested*, and the police who have been doing the *arresting*.

Comment: I'll expand on the answer by nnnnnn at bit. 

Given the second second, let's analyze the phrase "Police have been arrested." Some type of police are the only ones who can arrest people. So the phrase means that some policemen were arrested by other policemen. That isn't the intention of the sentence.

Comment: "Have been arrested" is simply grammatically incorrect. The present perfect requires a present participle, which "arrested" is not.

Comment: @MaxW "Police have been arrested by... erm... themselves"

Answer (score 1):

> Police have arrested two men in connection with the robbery

This is a statement in the active voice. There is a subject (police) a verb (have arrested) and an object (two men)

> Police have been arrested two men in connection with the robbery.

In this sentence, the verb has changed to passive voice (has been arrested): like this, it is not grammatically correct. To use passive voice correctly, you omit the subject (police) and move the object (two men) in front of the verb:

> Two men have been arrested in connection with the robbery.

We generally use passive voice when we don't want to say who is doing something: this works because the subject is omitted. Here is some more information about [passive voice](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/active-and-passive-voice)

It is possible to specify the subject (or agent, as it is called in passive voice) by linking it to the verb using the preposition **by**.

> Two men have been arrested by police in connection with the robbery.

Comment: +1....Might want to be more explicit about whether or not the second sentence is proper grammar.